# Fetching alphanumeric values in a table in ascending order

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by, alphanumeric

I have a table Food which contains column Quantity(it contains values- 10 kg,32 kg,5 kg). I want to fetch Quantity values in acsending order .

Now I have query:

```
select Quantity from Food
```

output=>

10 kg

32 kg

5 kg

But expected result is :

5 kg

10 kg

32 kg

How can I sort this alphanumeric value in SQL?

Comment: Does it contain weights in other units too, like 400gr or, God forbid, 20oz?

Comment: It contains units like gram,kg etc

Comment: If you have units like that, you need to re-calculate them to a single unit, for instance make grammes of all of them. You can do it in the query, but I think it's better to choose one unit and store it like that.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT Quantity from Food ORDER BY CAST(Quantity as UNSIGNED) DESC;
```

This isn't ideal, you should store the quantity as an integer field and the unit as an enum.

Comment: or  **`ORDER BY Quantity+0`**  (implicit data conversion to numeric due to addition operation).

Answer (score 1):

If the unit is only `kg` then you can try like below. See a demo fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e644f/6

```
select Quantity from Food
order by replace(Quantity,'kg','') * 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the actual data you can grab the numeric part from the front of the value and than order by it:

```
SELECT Quantity 
  FROM Food 
 ORDER BY CAST(LEFT(Quantity,INSTR(Quantity,' ')-1) AS DECIMAL) DESC;
```

However as @Martin indicates MySQL appear to do that much for you. This is more explicit and there is, perhaps, value in that.